# qwt example The program has unexpectedly finished

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qwt

something is wrong wiht my code , when I execute my program(an example of QWT) I get this error( program has unexpectedly finished )Why am I getting this error message and how can I fix it?

Thanks

here are my code:

```
    main.cpp
        #include "mainwindow.h"
        #include <QtGui>
        #include <QApplication>

        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        {

        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();
        w.resize(400, 450);

        return a.exec();
        }
    mainwindow.cpp

      #include "mainwindow.h"


    MainWindow:: MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent)

    {

    CreateGui();

    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {

    }


    void MainWindow::CreateGui()
    {

        QwtPlot *myPlot = new QwtPlot(centralWidget());
            QwtPlotCurve *courbe = new QwtPlotCurve("Courbe 1");
            QLineEdit *test = new QLineEdit;

            QVector<double> x(5);
            QVector<double> y(5);

            // On entre des valeurs
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                x.append((double)i);
                y.append((double)(5-i));
            }
            courbe->setSamples(x.data(),y.data(),x.size());
            myPlot->replot();

            courbe->attach(myPlot);
            QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
            layout->addWidget(myPlot, 0, 1);
            layout->addWidget(test,1,0);
            centralWidget()->setLayout(layout);


        }

      and mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include<QLineEdit>
#include<QGridLayout>

#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent=0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
 private slots:
    void CreateGui();
};







#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Answer (score -1):

in mainwindow.h

CreateGui is not a slot, maybe it can be, bot for now it is not asociated to any connect(signal, slot)

<strike>MainWindow(QWidget *parent=0); comes without that explicit, i dont know what you want to say with explicit. :S</strike>
(explicit is fine, thanks to @frank)

in mainwindow.cpp

instead of centralWidget() you would add a this keyword, and trying to render on the MainWindow widget, wich inherits from QWidget.

something like this:

on mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::CreateGui()
{

    QwtPlot *myPlot = new QwtPlot(this);
    QwtPlotCurve *courbe = new QwtPlotCurve("Courbe 1");
    QLineEdit *test = new QLineEdit;

    QVector<double> x(5);
    QVector<double> y(5);

    // On entre des valeurs
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        x.append((double)i);
        y.append((double)(5-i));
    }
    courbe->setSamples(x.data(),y.data(),x.size());
    myPlot->replot();

    courbe->attach(myPlot);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->addWidget(myPlot, 0, 1);
    layout->addWidget(test,1,0);
    this->setLayout(layout);


}
```

Or set the centralWidget to something, as there is no setCentralWidget(QWidget*) call anywhere, as @frank name it.

the doc says that [centralWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget) will return zero if it is not setted before.
and shows you a link to the [setCentralWidget(qwidget*)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) method.

i added that line @frank said on the constructor.

```
this->setCentralWidget(new QWidget);
```

after that it works too. i have never used those methods before, but apparently the last is the preferred way to use it.

Greetings!

Comment: anyways, the 'explicit' and the 'slot' things are not the reason why you program fails. The error is in the CreateGui(). (where also the first C of the (any) method name should be lowercase).

but the other two keywords just are there to over-complicate a very simple example.

Comment: `explicit` is good style and should be kept. centralWidget() is also to be preferred to this (to not break the overall mainwindow layout), although a setCentralwidget(new QWidget) in the beginning might be indeed what's causing the crash.Running it in a debugger would help.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, you are right, but i did pointed out on the comment that those two thing were not causing the seg fault, but the centralWidget() method.

I have never used centralWidget, but now that i have looked on the docs [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget), indeed there is a setCentralWidget() wich when setted as you mention, centralWidget() returns a valid pointer.

It should be always setted if you use centralWidget()?

i added the line "this->setCentralWidget(new QWidget);" on the constructor and then works.

Comment: thank you Frank and rccursach, my code works now but when I try adding any button the button remains at upper left corner,I add button like this  QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->addWidget(myPlot, 0, 1);
    layout->addWidget(test,1,0);
     QPushButton *StartButton= new QPushButton("Start",this);
    QHBoxLayout *layout1 =new QHBoxLayout;
    layout1->addWidget(StartButton);
    QVBoxLayout *layoutprincipale=new QVBoxLayout;
    layoutprincipale->addLayout(layout);
    layoutprincipale->addLayout(layout1);

Comment: if i'm not wrong, that's because you do:
"new QPushButton("Start",this)", where this is your MainWindow, but your plot and layout were on another QWidget setted on setCentralWidget(), so you should do too "new QPushButton("Start",centralWidget())", so centralWidget's pointee QWidget is the parent of the button you added, as it is for the layout.
Good Luck!